# Django REST Framework: create related model from POSTed data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Using the following models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    [some irrelevant fields]

class TicketComment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
```

I created the following serializers:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    [irrelevant]

class TicketCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketComment
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return TicketComment.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

A view:

```
class TicketCommentView(APIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'ticket_id'

    def post(self, request, ticket_id):
        data = request.data
        data['creator'] = 'joe'

        try:
            data['ticket'] = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
        except Ticket.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound('Ticket {} does not exist.'.format(ticket_id))

        serializer = TicketCommentSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        comment = serializer.save()

        return Response(comment, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And URL pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('ticket/<int:ticket_id>/comment', TicketCommentView.as_view()),
]
```

However, when trying to POST the data `{"text": "test"}`, it fails with:

```
"ticket": ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Ticket."]
```

If I change the view to pass the `ticket_id` integer instead of the ticket instance, it complains about duplicate keys:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ticketcomment_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(41993) already exists.
```

How can I create a resource and attach it to an existing related object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing ticket as serializer data, pass it to serializer's save method directly([related part](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) of docs):

```
def post(self, request, ticket_id):
    data = request.data

    try:
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
    except Ticket.DoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound('Ticket {} does not exist.'.format(ticket_id))

    serializer = TicketCommentSerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    comment = serializer.save(ticket=ticket, creator='joe')

    return Response(comment, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Note in `TicketCommentSerializer` you should leave only text field:

```
class TicketCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketComment
        fields = ['text']
```

Comment: Ha, that makes sense. Though, I want the fields to be `__all__` because I also use the serializer for GET requests on the ticket. Should the fields other than `text` be marked as `required=False` since I don't require them when POSTing a new comment?

Comment: @mart1n Yes, I suppose it will work. You may also set `read_only=True`for fields which is not supposed to be posted by users.

Comment: Ah, that's much better since I can use the `read_only_fields` Meta option. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

First you should not include `id` in serializer, cause mostly it will be a auto increment value. That is why you are getting an `Integrity Error`.

Comment: It's not the ID of the comment I'm passing, it's the ID of the related ticket which will end up being the foreign key in the DB.

Comment: Unique constraint will only allow key once that did you check that?

Comment: You can see in the model definitions that the `ForeignKey` doesn't have any unique constraints; the model would have to use `OneToOneField` for that.